# Automated smoke testing of windows froms

Tags: automated-tests, smoke-testing

We've got two windows form application we'd like to run automated smoke tests. The first one is Content maker, in this app user can create formulas and trees and ... . The second one is calculator, this app use the content and outputs (Database and XML files) of first app.

In first App (Content maker) we can use smoke tests easily, but in second one it's impossible to use smoke tests, because the contents was created by user and how we can check the results? 
I was wondering if anyone could suggest existing frameworks or applications that would help with that.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it depends on what *kind* of smoke test you want to do, function level or integration level. Functional level means your smoke test will only need the application under test, integration level means you need both of the applications' environment setup.

For functional level test, the dependency could be mocked or static. For integration level test, as you realized that your verification points may be less. A workaround would be let user always use predefined data in that environment for smoke test.